# Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue on Initial Load

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-management, ios-simulator

So I am currently building an app, do display some user analytics. In order to check if all my background calculations and the corresponding plots look descent, I have written a function to generate some mock Data, called `addMockData` and looks something like this:

```
func addMockdata() {
    let ClassToHoldData = ClassToHoldData()
    for i in 0...15 {

        let otherClassToHoldData = otherClassToHoldData()

        for j in 0...12000 {
            let fx = ...
            let fy = ...
            let fz = ...

            fx.append(...)
            fy.append(...)
            fz.append(...)

        }

        otherClassToHoldData.fx = fx
        otherClassToHoldData.fy = fy
        otherClassToHoldData.fz = fz


   ClassToHoldData.info.append(otherClassToHoldData)

    try! realm.write {
            realm.objects(UserModel.self)[index].data.append(ClassToHoldData)
    }
}
```

I call addMockData in the AppDelegate under the `application(...)` method. Thus when I build and run the app for the first time `addMockData` gets called. This works fine in the simulator and the data is generated without a hitch and memory usage peaking at around 450 Mb when generating the mock data.

The issue arises when I run the program on an actual device, in my case an Ipad Air (3rd Gen). There after generating roughly half of the mock data, it terminates with the message "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue". The memory usage steadily rises until it reaches roughly 1.7 Gb, when it crashes. It seems like it does not deallocate all the data generated in the for loop.

I have tried wrapping my for loops in a `autoreleasepool{}` and have checked that Zombie Objects are disabled.

What else could I try? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398746/message-from-debugger-terminated-due-to-memory-issue)

Comment: I think you should probably enable zombie objects to check if you have them, and also run diagnostics to see what's going on. Still, expecting 450 Mb to be ok on mobile app is ridiculous. You should be rather using some sort of cloud service to store such amounts.

Comment: Hi Kiril, thanks for your reply. I'll see if it makes a difference. To your point, in my final build, I plan to install the app without the extensive mock data. But as it currently stands, I need to have some versions that are populated with data in order to show the app and see where potential issues may arise. So when the "show" app is installed for the first time, that is when addMockData gets called and the memory issue comes up.Once installed and the data has been added, the memory usage is stable at around 100-120 Mb.So how I can generate a boatload of mock data without crahsing the app?